# Get data if time greater than 30

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get data from database if time of each data greater than 30, actually I try to delete each item after 30 days, but for now I trying to select data, I will change query to delete later. I set my code in cronjob, this is my query:

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM ads WHERE time >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY");
```

It return data as an array but the problem is some data are less than 30 days. What I have missed?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 151 //2018-01-18 19:35:49
    [1] => 164 //2018-01-25 22:56:16
    [2] => 198 //2018-02-01 11:05:09
    [3] => 203 //2018-02-04 20:36:34
)
```

Update: time is timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting all results lesser than 30 days because your operator is the inverse of that you want :

```
SELECT id FROM ads WHERE time <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Will give you the records before than 30 days from now.